# Google Now "not eligible" after switching from personal account to G Suite account

Tags: google-apps

I switched an Android phone (Google Pixel) from using a personal Google Account to a G Suite account and everything seems to be working fine except *Google Now* which shows the following error when accessing it:

*"This account is not eligible for the feed".*

Switching back to a personal account makes it work again, but of course that's not an option.

I found a few references online to countries not being eligible but this is not applicable in this case as I am in the U.S.

Comment: So why was this downvoted? Google tech support doesn't know the answer so who else to ask than "superusers" ?

Comment: If you read the descriptions of both tags that you tagged this post with, you will see both are off-topic and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, the question is about the interaction between both so it would be off-topic on both sites. So you're basically saying "we don't want to help, even if there's a good chance someone will know the answer". Thanks

Comment: Out of random curiosity - have you tried factory reset and set up with just the G Suite account (and no personal account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Google Product forum help     [How to Enable Google Now for Google Apps for Work??!!](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/apps/xFCJYydtx4E)

> **Question**: ....Can someone help me to Enable Google Now for our Google Apps for Work account?
>   I am an Admin.
>
> **Best Answer**: I got the actual answer from Live Chat support, and it is totally different from what the support docs say. Here is where to find it: 
>   Admin console > Device Management > Mobile > Device Management settings > Android settings > Enable Google Now (also applies to iOS)

Note: Google Apps for Work is [repackaged](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/34848/20160930/meet-g-suite-repackaged-google-work-apps.htm) as G Suite

Trust that solves